# AG Grid don't install with REACT 18

Tags: reactjs, npm, ag-grid

I am trying to flow this tutorial
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/
and When I tried this
`npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-react`
And show this error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ag-grid@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0" from ag-grid-react@27.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ag-grid-react
npm ERR!   ag-grid-react@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-08T00_42_18_101Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-08T00_45_54_675Z-debug-0.log
```

I am confuse because in the Documentation says :

````
React Version   AG Grid Versions
15.x    18 -    21.2.0
16.3+ / 17+     22+ ```

Looks like my only option is to downgrade my REACT Version. 
I am in 18.0.0 . Do you know if I have other options?
````

Answer (score 0):

I edited the package.json with those settings, to do the downgrade to React 17.0.2 :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  },

Run the 
npm install
and 
npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-react
Works with no issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see ag-grid showing as compatible with React v18 yet

[image: react version chart]

You can avoid errors like this by using yarn instead of npm

`yarn install`

Then you'll just get a warning instead of a failed build, ie

`warning " > ag-grid-react@27.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0".`